# Use Spinner to open another class

Tags: java, android-studio, dropdown, spinner, adapter

Trying to use this code to open a class from a dropdown list on a spinner. So if help is pressed the help activity opens and if navigation is pressed the navigation class opens

```
//declare spinner.
        Spinner dropdown = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String[] items = new String[]{"Help", "Navigation Help"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);

        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
        
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int pos, long id) {
       
        
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have used findViewById(...) , I assume that you are setting onItemSelectedListener in an Activity.

```
Context context = this;
HashMap<String , Class> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("Naviagtion" , NavigationActivity.class);
hashMap.put("Help" ,HelpActivity.class);

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int pos, long id) {
       String string = adapter.getItem(pos);
       Intent intent = new Intent(context , hashMap.get(string));
       startActivity(intent);
}
```